# How To run Azure Log Analytics query api, Using python?

Tags: json, python-3.x, azure, azure-devops, azure-api-management

I have been trying to run a log analytics query using python it was running on the below query

```
os.system("curl -X POST \'https://api.loganalytics.io/v1/workspaces/0000000000000000000000-0000-c05f0ccc198d/query\' -d \'{\"query\": \"ContainerLog\",\"timespan\": \"PT12H\"}\' -H \'Authorization:Bearer"+auth+" \' -H \'Content-Type: application/json\'")
```

but it's not working on the below query

```
os.system("curl -X POST \'https://api.loganalytics.io/v1/workspaces/0000000000000000000000-c05f0ccc198d/query\' -d \'{\"query\": \"search in (ContainerLog) \"error\" | where TimeGenerated > datetime(\"2020-09-09\") | project LogEntry\"}\' -H \'Authorization:Bearer "+auth+"\' -H \'Content-Type: application/json\'")
```

Error :

{"error":{"message":"The request had some invalid properties","code":"BadArgumentError","correlationId":"3cf07489-2a00-4ef6-9c00-15bd7d1be648","details":[{"code":"InvalidJsonBody","message":"Unexpected token e in JSON at position 38","target":null}],"innererror":{"code":"QueryValidationError","message":"Failed parsing the query"}}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use single quote instead of double quote for `\"error\"` and `\"2020-09-09\"`.

For example, use `\'error\'` instead of `\"error\"`; use `datetime(\'2020-09-09\')` instead of `datetime(\"2020-09-09\")`

The query looks like below:

```
os.system("curl -X POST \'https://api.loganalytics.io/v1/workspaces/0000000000000000000000-c05f0ccc198d/query\' -d \'{\"query\": \"search in (ContainerLog) \'error\' | where TimeGenerated > datetime(\'2020-09-09\') | project LogEntry\"}\' -H \'Authorization:Bearer "+auth+"\' -H \'Content-Type: application/json\'")
```

Comment: {"error":{"message":"The request had some invalid properties","code":"BadArgumentError","correlationId":"086c0ed6-3058-4dc1-95b6-9c22a2db1044","innererror":{"code":"SemanticError","message":"A semantic error occurred.","innererror":{"code":"SEM0100","message":"'where' operator: Failed to resolve scalar expression named 'error'"}}}}

Comment: @pappu.jerin, please try use this query `search in (ContainerLog) 'error' | where TimeGenerated > datetime('2020-09-09') | project LogEntry` in this [page](https://dev.loganalytics.io/apiexplorer/postQuery?apiKey=DEMO_KEY&appId=DEMO_WORKSPACE), and see if the error still occurs.

Comment: and please remember fill in the 'Workspace ID' and 'API Key' field with your real value.

Answer (score 1):

```
   use the below code 

    import requests
    url = "https://api.loganalytics.io/v1/workspaces/{workspace_id}/query"
    
    payload = "{\"query\": \"search in (ContainerLog) 'error' | top 50 by TimeGenerated asc   | project LogEntry\"}"
    headers = {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer access token',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    
    response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data = payload)
```